# Postfix and assembly language trouble ?Is this correct?

Tags: assembly

I have to write in postfix and assembly for a stack machine

1. `(a+b*c)/(a+d*c-e)`
2. `5+(3*7)-8`

So for the first part `(a+b*c)/(a+d*c-e)` I wrote:

```
PUSH B
PUSH C
MUL
PUSH A 
ADD
PUSH D
PUSH C
MUL
PUSH A
ADD
PUSH E
SUB
DIV
POP
```

So, A is `$s1`, B is `$s2`, C is `$s3` and D is `$s4` and E is `$s5`

```
Mul $t0,$s1,$s2
Add $s1,$s2,$s3
Mul $t2,$s3,$s4
```

How to continue this now?

The second part `5+(3*7)-8`:

```
PUSH 3
PUSH 7
MUL
PUSH 5
ADD
PUSH 8
SUB
POP
```

How about the assembly of this? I mean, since these are numbers, I cant use `$s1`, I must use `#` right ?

Comment: What has postfix to do with your question? Also, which architecture are you using?

Answer (score 0):

(a+b*c)/(a+d*c-e)

If you need the "stupid" solution that doesn't rearrange anything you should write instead:

```
push a
push b
push c
mul
add
push a
push d
push c
mul
add
push e
sub
div
```

For the rest the context isn't clear. So what are a b c d ?
Are these variables stored somewhere in memory ?
Are you going to use the floating point coprocessor or are you going to do integer arithmetic ?

Comment: Yes,they are variables.Integer arithmetic.

Comment: But when you write 
push a
push b
push c
mul

You are writing a*b*c

Answer (score 0):

So what do you mean in postfix and assembly ?

It isn't possible to do both unless a stack processor is used.

So that could be possible with the floating point coprocessor.

Instead if you have to use only the processor, if you have to write optimized code 
then you should do some rearrangements in order to reorder things and optimize.

I suppose the problem is about the mathematical coprocessor because the sequence of instructions you wrote hasn't computational sense using the x86 instructions.
Please clarify.

Comment: The problem states exactly what I have written.I have to write it in postfix first and then in assembly.I was wrong about the x86 architecture,I confused it with another thing,sorry

Answer (score 0):

Writting in postfix means converting the infix notation to postfix.

That means converting:

(a+b*c)/(a+d*c-e) ==> a b c * + a d c * e - /

That hasn't to do anything with the processor.

Now if you need to write that in assembly you should state wich processor you use.
Is it x86 ?

Comment: A stack machine, consumes essentially postfix code, so what you had written at the beggining is OK !